# phpunit installation on xampp through pear

Tags: php, phpunit, xampp

I'm trying to install PHPunit through pear using xampp. I'm getting the following error when I give pear channel-discover components.ez.no

C:\xampp\php>pear channel-discover components.ez.no
Discovery of channel "components.ez.no" failed (channel-add: Cannot open "http:/
/components.ez.no/channel.xml" (Connection to `components.ez.no:80' failed: No 
connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
))

please help me in this. what could be the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, that site [has been up and down](http://www.silverstripe.org/installing-silverstripe/show/15591) over the last few weeks. Try going to *http://components.ez.no/channel.xml* in your browser and if it shows the XML, then trying running the command.

If that doesn't work, try updating PEAR.

Comment: i updated pear, and now i'm getting another error along with it. And i'm getting this for not just pear channel-discover components.ez.no but also for pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com & pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de .

Comment: the error i get is:C:\xampp\php>pear channel-discover components.ez.no
Discovering channel components.ez.no over http:// failed with message: channel-a
dd: Cannot open "http://components.ez.no/channel.xml" (Connection to `components
.ez.no:80' failed: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)

Comment: Trying to discover channel components.ez.no over https:// instead
Discovery of channel "components.ez.no" failed (channel-add: Cannot open "https://components.ez.no/channel.xml" (Connection to `components.ez.no:443' failed: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?))

Answer (score 0):

I'm just over this error about components.ez.no being down and discovered that there's a workaround:

You should download EZ Components package from http://ezcomponents.org/download and extract those to php\pear\ezc

Then, use official website for PEAR package of PHPUnit and get Skeleton_Generator package open to find:
phpunit-skelgen.bat
phpunit-skelgen.php

Extract these to php/ (you should already have phpunit.bat / phpunit file there)

I hope I could be of any help. Good luck!